# How to query a Hierarchical Category tree entity with undefined depth

Tags: java, spring-boot, tree

I have created a hierachy structure or a tree structure for a shopping site using springboot. My problem is how to query such a structure when looking for a specific product and its parents:

```
id,  category_name,   parent_id
'1', 'Electronics',      NULL
'2', 'Gaming',           NULL
'3', 'Home Audio',       '1'
'4', 'Console',          '2'
'5', 'Sony',             '4'
'6', 'Karaoke',          '3'
```

This is what i have done, any pointers on what i need to do on the entity to achieve this structure and also how i can query it i.e

> It is also important to note that i am using **postgres database**

1. findAllProducts in a category and
2. find all categories linked to a product.

**Category Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String categoryName;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
        private Category parent;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<Category> children = new ArrayList<Category>();

    // Getter and setter removed for readability    
}
```

**Product Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    private String name;

    private int quantity;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "products_categories", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private List<Category> categories;

  // getters and setter omitted for readability

}
```

**Category Service**

```
public class CategoryService {

@Autowired
private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

public void addCategory(Category category) {
    categoryRepository.save(category);
}
}
```

**Product Service**

```
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        productRepository.save(product);
    }
   }
```

Comment: From an SQL perspective, check for `connect by prior` clause.

Comment: i am creating the database from these entities using **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create**

Comment: It seems the answer is in the question. What's the concrete question/problem about the code you posted?

Comment: the code doesnt create that structure when i use it, so when i try to create categories and link them to products.

Comment: Well, you didn't post the code trying to create that structure, so how could we help?

Comment: i added the code

Comment: No, you didn'tt. Where is the code creating the category Electronics with no parent, the category Gaming with no parent, the category Home Audio with Electronics as parent, etc.?

Comment: i am trying to create code that can create such a structure and the code i added is what i have done thus far and i would like help in getting my current code to a stage where it creates such a structure

Comment: What makes you think you're not already there if you haven't even tried doing what you want?

Comment: I get this error when i try to create a product , org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Comment: So, do what the error message says. If you need help, once again, post the code.

Comment: you were right it persists fine however querying the tree is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a recursive query to select the parents of a given category.

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;

public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {

  @Query(
      value = "WITH RECURSIVE ancestors(id, parent_id, category_name, lvl) AS ("
          + "   SELECT cat.id, cat.parent_id, cat.category_name, 1 AS lvl "
          + "   FROM categories cat "
          + "   WHERE cat.id = :categoryId "
          + "   UNION ALL "
          + "   SELECT parent.id, parent.parent_id, parent.category_name, child.lvl + 1 AS lvl "
          + "   FROM categories parent "
          + "   JOIN ancestors child "
          + "   ON parent.id = child.parent_id "
          + " )"
          + "SELECT category_name from ancestors ORDER BY lvl DESC"
      , nativeQuery = true)
  List<String> findAncestry(@Param("categoryId") Long categoryId);
}
```

Following is a test that creates the category hierarchy and queries it:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.List;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class HierarchyTest {

  @Autowired
  CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

  @Test
  public void testCategoryRepository() {
    String[] electronicsCategoryNames = {"Electronics", "Home Audio", "Karaoke"};
    String[] gamingCategoryNames = {"Gaming", "Console", "Sony"};

    Category karaoke = createCategories(electronicsCategoryNames);
    Category sony = createCategories(gamingCategoryNames);

    findAncestry(karaoke, electronicsCategoryNames);
    findAncestry(sony, gamingCategoryNames);
  }

  Category createCategories(String[] categoryNames) {
    Category parent = null;

    for (String categoryName : categoryNames) {
      Category category = new Category();
      category.setCategoryName(categoryName);
      category.setParent(parent);
      parent = categoryRepository.save(category);
    }

    Assert.assertNotNull("category.id", parent.getId());
    return parent;
  }


  void findAncestry(Category category, String[] categoryNames) {
    List<String> ancestry = categoryRepository.findAncestry(category.getId());
    Assert.assertEquals("ancestry.size", categoryNames.length, ancestry.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < categoryNames.length; i++) {
      Assert.assertEquals("ancestor " + i, categoryNames[i], ancestry.get(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this was tested on H2 and PostgreSQL databases. You might need to modify the native query according to the actual database you are using.

PostgreSQL has excellent documentation on how this works, see:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-with.html

Comment: how do i modify the query for use in postgres